# I want help and ideas in solving upload file and do some task in background Laravel or NodeJs

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, redis, socket.io

I want to upload excel file to server(laravel) and import data of excel to server but I realize that if I excel file have more data (about thousands of row) server will hold the request till import progress finished, I can edit php.ini to increase max time but hold request too long can make server ddos when multi user upload file at the same time.
So I want to separate request into two part, upload file and import data(run in background and send percent to end user - realtime update).
I know queue and jobs but when use jobs it seem like i cant stop it and queue can't handle if multi user upload.
For example if user A upload a very big file
while user A uploading, user B upload a file to server and user B must wait user A upload complete. It may cause annoy for end user
Any good ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Laravel Queues](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues) for this. I recommend you to use `redis` or `beanstalkd` driver for queue. Queues are used if you want to do long process tasks in the background.

Comment: Thanks for helping me but if full queue end user must wait long time

Comment: Yes that's correct. If you have a very long process it is expected to be long. But using Laravel Queues, the end user may close the browser, then return to the site again to check if the process is completed since the process is ran on the server side.